# PHP: How to convert html to unicode?

Tags: php, html, unicode, anchor

```
$url='%EA%B3%A0%EC%B9%B4%EC%A7%80%EB%85%B8';

echo '<a href="/'.$url.'">'.$url.'</a>';
```

And it shows the url is: **mywebsite.com/고카지노** with anchor:

```
%EA%B3%A0%EC%B9%B4%EC%A7%80%EB%85%B8
```

Can you show me how to convert anchor to **고카지노**? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
$url = urldecode('%EA%B3%A0%EC%B9%B4%EC%A7%80%EB%85%B8');
echo "<a href='/$url'>$url</a>";

// Results in:
// <a href="/고카지노">고카지노</a>
```

Comment: Please don't do this without re-encoding the result as HTML.  As written, if `$url` is controlled by an attacker, then they can run arbitrary JavaScript, for example by using a value like `%27%20onclick=%27alert%28%29`

Comment: @Mike Samuel, hello, I don't quite understand. How to fix it ?

Comment: @Ban, ["How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) has some good answers.

Comment: @Mike Samuel, Hello, I used htmlspecialchars_decode but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ban, you have a string of URL encoded bytes that you want to embed in HTML.  Use `urldecode` to get a string of plain text, then `htmlspecialchars` to get a string of HTML.  `$url = htmlspecialchars(urldecode($x))`.